# In vue mousehover event

Tags: vue.js

I am newbie in VueJS, how to animate div when mousehover, or keyup ?

This is what I tried so far,

```
<div id="demo">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


*{ margin:0; padding:0 }

.menu {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:30px; overflow:hidden; background:gray}
.menu.active { height:auto; transition:0.5s all; overflow:visible }
.menu li { height:30px;}


new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: { 
  }
})
```

I am trying to add class "active" to  "menu" div tag when keyup or  mousehover.
Also when mouseout or keydown,  remove the "active" class.

here is the demo https://codepen.io/ezrinn/pen/JjXwpaP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need a hover effect. You don't need javascript for this, just `:hover` in css should work, basically change your `.menu.active` to `.menu:hover`:

```
.menu:hover { height:auto; transition:0.5s all; overflow:visible }
```

https://codepen.io/leopsidom/pen/QWEjEWa